# get last day of the month from year month in python

Tags: python, date, monthcalendar

I need to get first and last day of a month based on the given yearmonth value. I am able to get the first day, how do we get the last day of the month here ( in python) :

```
from datetime import date
def first_day_of_month(year,month):
    return date(year, month, 1)

print "Today: %s" % date.today()
print ("First day of this month: %s" %
first_day_of_month(2015,10))
```

This gives the output:
Today: 2015-10-26
First day of this month: 2015-10-01

How to fetch the last day of the month? P.s : **I do not want to give 31 as the third parameter for date() function. I want to calculate number of days in the month and then pass on that to the function.**

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? For example, why not subtract one day from the start of the following month?

Comment: I tried calendar method to get monthrange, and that way I could do it but I wanted to use date function as I used that for first day. below method suggested by @Busturdust is what I was looking for

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html):

```
from calendar import monthrange
monthrange(2011, 2)
(1, 28)
# Just to be clear, monthrange supports leap years as well:

from calendar import monthrange
monthrange(2012, 2)
(2, 29)
```

> "Return weekday (0-6 ~ Mon-Sun) and number of days (28-31) for year, month."

Comment: You may want to explain the return value of `monthrange`: "Return weekday (0-6 ~ Mon-Sun) and number of days (28-31) for year, month."  (So OP would want `month_end = monthrange(year, month)[1]`.)  Your `datetime` solution requires extra logic to handle the first and last month of the year.  I would omit it as the `monthrange` solution is more than adequate.  Also, you have a typo -- you have a backtick before `from`.